# Office JS application.createDocument() opens new window with closed add-in

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers, openoffice-api

We are loading a `base64` document from the backend and opening it in our Word-addin (using Office JS APIs). We are using `application.createDocument(base64)` to do so. This causes the Word application to open an entirely new window for the new document, in which the addin is closed by default.

Our add-in is login protected, so re-opening the addin requires the users to put in user/password again.

Is there a way to 1) not open a new MS-Word window (replace the word document), or 
2) open a new MS-Word window with the addin already open and pass the authentication tokens from the first MS-Word to the second?

Comment: was it resovled?